# I want to get number of CenterMeeting between give two date on that case

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
case when @mode='TwoDays'
then CenterMeetingDay between datepart(dw,GETDATE()-1) and DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()+1) 
end CenterMeetingDay
```

Comment: form me you want to return integer that present current day of week, so you need to use DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()). Every day between day - and day + will be current day

Comment: please show some sample data and expected resuklt

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you cannot simply put a boolean comparison as the `when` clause.

So, include the condition in the `when` and be explicit about the return values:

```
(case when @mode = 'TwoDays' and
           CenterMeetingDay between datepart(dw, GETDATE() - 1) and DATEPART(DW, GETDATE() + 1) 
      then 1 else 0
 end) as CenterMeetingDay
```

In a `where` clause, you can do:

```
where ( (@mode = 'TwoDays') and CenterMeetingDay between datepart(dw, GETDATE() - 1) and DATEPART(DW, GETDATE() + 1)) or
      ( (@mode <> 'TwoDays' . . . )
```

or:

```
where (case when @mode = 'TwoDays' and
                 CenterMeetingDay between datepart(dw, GETDATE() - 1) and DATEPART(DW, GETDATE() + 1) 
            then 1 else 0
       end) = 1
```

Comment: i use this in where clause:
  where ApprovedDate is not null
and ApprovedDate<>'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
and  case when @mode='TwoDays' then CenterMeetingDay 
between datepart(dw,GETDATE()-1) and DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()+1) end CenterMeetingDay
--and DisbursementMode='DM1'
and HO_ValidationFlag=1
and DATEdiff(d,HO_ValidationDate,GETDATE())>2